Hibernate fetches proxy objects along with non-proxied objects after upgrading to 6.1.7.Final
I have an entity that has a one-to-one mapping with itself.
@Entity
public class DeviceEntity {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @OneToOne(cascade = {PERSIST}, fetch = LAZY)
 private DeviceEntity predecessor;

 //Some other fields

}

At this point, I have two records in the db like the following.



id
predecessor_id
...




1
null
...


2
1
...



I am trying to fetch some devices using the following query:
em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DeviceEntity d " +
    " WHERE d.id IN :idList", DeviceEntity.class)
    .setParameter("idList", deviceIdList)
    .getResultList();

In my case deviceIdList = [1, 2]
Earlier, I was using Hibernate 5.6.15.Final, and this query fetched both entities when [1, 2] was passed as the idList. However, now it fetches the device with the 2nd ID as a proxy object. I have enabled Hibernate logs and noticed there is a database hit as well.
Changing the query to fetch the predecessor explicitly has solved the issue, but I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't involve fetching unnecessary data. How can I resolve this issue efficiently in the upgraded 6.1.7.Final version?

You marked the field as lazy which will generate a proxy for that field, The whole point of the lazy is to use a proxy so it doesn't retrieve all the data at once.

@M.Deinum Yeah, but it was fetched as a fully initialized object in the previous version. It should not be a proxy since id: 2 is in the list I'm passing to the query.

Which was wrong due to the lazy. So it now basically works correct, if you want to retrieve it either don't mark it lazy or change your query to eagerly fetch it.

Getting the predecessor as a proxy is the expected behavior. However, getting Device 2 as a proxy is not correct, I believe. Eagerly fetching it will solve the issue, but it will load unwanted Device objects into memory. For example, if Device 2 has a predecessor as Device 3, I don't need it since I'm only fetching Devices 1 and 2.

That is not how Hibernate works, it will only take the IN into account for the toplevel objects not the childs. So if there are others that aren't in the list as a child they will still be loaded, that isn't conditionallly. If you want that write a dedicated query for that instead of the simple one you have now. Your JPQL you have written doesn't make sense either SELECT s FROM DeviceEntity d there is no s defined so it wouldn't even run afaik.

Yeah, it's a mistake. It should be 'SELECT s FROM DeviceEntity d'.
